# ignite microservice cicd issues

Tags: java, git, ignite

I am implementing an Ignite cluster with data node, service, node and API node (Spring Boot with embedded ignite client). I have common POJO classes and DTO. Is there a good solution to store all nodes at single repository (sharing common POJO) to implement entire unit testing for the cluster. Same time I need to separate cicd pipelines for different node commits.
1st target: redeploy all nodes when the changes in common POJOs.
2nd target: deploy service nodes only when business logic changes.

My goal is complex unit-testing and change safety for neighbor nodes.
Also, if it matters, we plan to put each node to a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

In CICD usually makes sense to restart everything when anything changes to minimize chance of retaining any old state.

In Apache Ignite tests, the whole Ignite cluster is usually restarted for every single test, so it can be pretty efficient.

Comment: Does this correspond to microservices ideology? If i do changes for service node that does some messaging, is it worth rebooting the entire cluster?

Comment: Apache Ignite clusters are usually homogenous, so rebooting a microservice usually means rebooting its cluster. There is no specialization such as "this node does X, that node does Y"

Comment: Here https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/running-microservices-top-memory-data-grid-part-i  Apace Ignite committer described an example of not homogenous Ignite claster. This led me to my solution. So i decided to organize repo with sub-modules.

Comment: You can do with some effort, but I would still advise a full reboot in CICD.